# Callback get response Sync kotlin

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, callback, kotlin

I'm tring to get the response of a callback in sync mode because I the value of the response is needed to all application to work, without this value ( token ) I can't continue to use the application.
This is my companion object inside the retrofit interface. I need to set the token before creation of a client.

What I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT :**

I put as this Logs as you write :

```
companion object {

    private var mToken: String = ""

    fun create(activity: Activity): MyPhoneInterface {
        Log.d("tokenMyPhoneInterface", activity.localClassName)
        getToken(activity)
        Log.d("tokenMyPhoneInterface", "client token $mToken")

        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor { chain ->
                    val request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                            .addHeader("Authorization", mToken).build()
                    chain.proceed(request)
                }.build()

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_HOST)
                .build()

        return retrofit.create(MyPhoneInterface::class.java)
    }

    private fun getToken(activity: Activity) {
        if(!activity.isFinishing && isJwtExpired(mToken)){
            val latch = CountDownLatch(1)
            (LoginManager(activity)).getToken(true, object : ServiceCallback<String> {
                override fun success(token: String) {
                    Log.d("tokenMyPhoneInterface", "token $token")
                    mToken = token
                    latch.countDown()
                }
                override fun failure(serviceError: ServiceError) {
                    Log.d("tokenMyPhoneInterface", serviceError.errorMessage)
                    latch.countDown()
                }
            })
            Log.d("tokenMyPhoneInterface", "before await ")
            latch.await()
            Log.d("tokenMyPhoneInterface", "after await")
        }
    }
}
```

But I the system is blocked in the latch.await() and the logs is :

05-14 18:19:00.127 848-848/com.italy.myphone D/tokenMyPhoneInterface: view.splash.activity.Splash
05-14 18:19:00.131 848-848/com.italy.myphone D/tokenMyPhoneInterface: before await

**EDIT answer2:**

```
sealed class TokenResult {
class Success(val token: String) : TokenResult()
class Error(val serviceError: ServiceError) : TokenResult()}



suspend fun getToken(activity: Activity): TokenResult {
return suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
    (LoginManager(activity)).getToken(true, object : ServiceCallback<String> {
        override fun success(token: String) {
            continuation.resume(TokenResult.Success(token))
        }

        override fun failure(serviceError: ServiceError) {
            continuation.resume(TokenResult.Error(serviceError))
        }
    })
}}
```

And this is how to I try to call the suspend function :

```
companion object {
    fun create(activity: Activity): MyPhoneInterface{
        Log.d("tokenMyPhoneInterface", activity.localClassName)


        var token = runBlocking {
            return@runBlocking getToken(activity)
        }


        Log.d("tokenMyPhoneInterface", "obtained token")

        Log.d("tokenMyPhoneInterface", "client token $tokenResult")

        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor { chain ->
                    val request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                            .addHeader("Authorization", "").build()
                    chain.proceed(request)
                }.build()

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_HOST)
                .build()

        return retrofit.create(MyPhoneInterface::class.java)
    }
}
```

That is inside an interface and this is the code that I use to call the interface/companion object in the activity :

```
    private val mMyPhoneInterface by lazy {
    MyPhoneInterface.create(activity)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end I use JavaRx in order to sync a callback.. this is the snippet.

```
fun getToken(loginManager: LoginManager): String {
return Single
        .create(SingleOnSubscribe<String> { emitter ->
            loginManager.getToken(object : TokenSimpleCallback {
                override fun onSuccess(token: String) {
                    emitter.onSuccess(token)
                }

                override fun onFailure(loginServiceError: LoginServiceError) {
                    emitter.onError(Throwable(loginServiceError.toString()))
                }
            })
        }).blockingGet()}
```

Comment: this helped me a lot. are there any opinions if this is good practice or are there any pitfalls that have been overlooked?

Answer (score 7):

The best way I know to get the response of a callback in sync mode is using
Coroutines and the function `suspendCancellableCoroutine`
In your case you can have this function:

```
suspend fun getToken(activity: Activity): TokenResult {
    return suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
        (LoginManager(activity)).getToken(true, object : ServiceCallback<String> {
            override fun success(token: String) {
                continuation.resume(TokenResult.Success(token))
            }

            override fun failure(serviceError: ServiceError) {
                continuation.resume(TokenResult.Error(serviceError))
            }
        })
    }
}

sealed class TokenResult {
    class Success(val token: String) : TokenResult()
    class Error(val serviceError: ServiceError) : TokenResult()
}
```

And in your `activity.onCreate`:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) = runBlocking {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val tokenResult = getToken(this)
    if(tokenResult is Error){
        finish()
        return@runBlocking
    }

    //create client here with tokenResult.token value
}
```

Give it a try and let me know...

**EDIT:** In the example I use `runBlocking` because `getToken` is a suspend function. In your own code you should handle this logic outside the activity.

**EDIT:**
To eneable coroutines in your project add the following lines in your gradle file:

```
dependencies {
//other dependencies
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:0.22.5"
}
kotlin {
    experimental {
        coroutines "enable"
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to import something ? because androd studio give me an error about suspendCancellableCoroutine

Comment: Isn't using coroutines for blocking calls backwards? You first set up everything for good-looking async code, then wrap it into `runBlocking`. It's in no way better than `CountDownLatch`.

Comment: The use of runBlocking function in the example is just to call suspend functions right inside the onCreate() fun. It is just to try the code.

Comment: And if I want to user getToken not in a activity? And when I create the client I want to give it back to another function?

Comment: Just call `getToken` whenever you want, in another suspend function or inside a coroutine. To learn more about coroutines read this: 
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md

Comment: I add your solution, but it doesn't work, it is blocked on a white page

Comment: That is because getToken take long to respond and the activity is blocked in the onCreate function. You should implement the whole thing outside the activity.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `latch.count`. It is equals to 1 and `latch.count > 1` is `false`. Then your function is returned. Just use `latch.await()` and it will await for one of callbacks.

Sorry if I am wrong, I don't have enough repo to comment.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work, I change it like you write but the system block at await without do nothing... I also post it in my answer

Comment: @AlessandroCandon Then, can you update code and provide formatted logs?

Comment: Thanks ) Then, it is looks like your function in activity don't calls callback methods. I mean, that problem is not in this code.

Comment: It is strange, why the activity will block this? I don't think it is possible because I only wait the response of the callback in order to construct the client. Do you know any workaround?

Comment: @AlessandroCandon Can you just call one of your callback methods in `getToken()` method and return? This should leave some info in logcat. And put some logs after `await()` call.